# Splitting Pentominoes into Congruent Shapes

Tags: co.combinatorics

Of all the ways of splitting the twelve pentominoes into two sets of six pieces each, how many are such that one can form two congruent shapes with the two sets?

I posted this question earlier at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2157912/splitting-pentominoes-into-congruent-shapes, with not replies.

Comment: Probably a more accessible (by hand) version would be which pairs (or triples, or quadruples) of pentominos combine to form a shape that is made by two (or three or four) different pentominos.  Suppose you draw a graph with vertices unordered pairs of tiles, and two vertices have an edge if  both pairs form the same shape.  If the graph were complete (or even dense enough) that would imply the answer to your question is 924.  Gerhard "Meaning All The Ways Work" Paseman, 2017.05.09.

Comment: What is the motivation for this type of question?

Comment: Wir müssen wissen — wir werden wissen! (David Hilbert)

Comment: Ich verstehe das, aber ... do you think this is something Hilbert would find interesting? If so, why? Do pentominoes have any algebraic or geometric structure? Is there any particular reason to consider that combinatorial set, as opposed to the multiset where we include the X twice, or where we leave out the 5x1 piece? If not, what connection do you expect with other parts of mathematics?